# Рассылка на сайте. Как защитится от скриптов, которые будут беспрерывно добавлять адреса

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, email, рассылка, site

Обычная почтовая рассылка. Пользователь вводит свое имя и почту на сайте и ему приходят уведомления о новых новостях.

Как защитится от скриптов, которые могут добавить 100500 случайных почтовых адресов в рассылку?

Comment: Хм, а такие бывают? Но даже если и бывают, способы классические: капча, ограничение на частоту запросов, всё такое

Comment: Как обычно защищаются от ботов - поставить капчу

Comment: Да, капча, наверно, будет самым надежным и простым решением.

Comment: @pank, подтверждение подписки добавьте через отправку письма с ссылкой активации, а то будите слать письма на несуществующие адреса или не тем людям которые подписались.